# Examples of Continuous Probability Distributions with Slowly Varying Upper Tail and Infinite Expectation

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, slowly-varying-functions

$L(x) = 1 - F(x)$ is the slowly varying upper tail, where F(x) is a continuous probability distribution function with infinite expectation. That is $\int_{0}^{\infty} u dF(u) = \infty$. I am unable to construct any such probability distribution and would like some examples with the specified properties.

Definition: A function $L(x)$ is said to be slowly varying at $\infty$ if $lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{L(\alpha x)}{L(x)} = 1 , \forall \alpha >0$, where $\alpha$ is a real number.

Comment: Think about the logarithm? Does it grow slowly?

Comment: Yeah I read that log x is a commonly used slowly varying function. I tried constructing expressions for PDFs using log x, but I am not able to reconcile these expressions with the fact that integrating them from 0 to $\infty$ should give me 1, nor am I able to achieve the infinite expectation condition.

Comment: Was that maybe a typo? Both $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{x+1}dx$ and $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x}{x+1}dx$ are infinite.

Comment: yes sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the cdf $F(x) = 1-\frac{1}{\log(x)}$ for $x\geq e$. Then $L(x) = \frac{1}{\log(x)}$ is slowly varying at infinity and if $X$ is a random variable with cdf $F$ then
$$\mathbb{E}[X] = \int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}(X>x) \, dx = \int_0^e 1 \, dx + \int_e^\infty \frac{dx}{\log(x)} = \infty.$$

Comment: Yeah thank you so much. Coincidentally, just before I opened this notification, I just thought of a similar CDF, $\frac{ln(x)}{ln(x)+1}$. Thank you so much.